# How check that there was scrolling action to element into view?

Tags: javascript, c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is there a way to check that after some manipulations on page, browser scroll into view an Element? And returns true or false after it. Maybe 
with JavaScriptExecutor we can do this

And words, I want to check the fact of scrolling

Comment: What is your exact question (manual step you are trying to automate) ?

Comment: fact of scrolling after click on button

Comment: are you trying to detect if the page scrolled on it's own so that you know where you're at on the page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow this steps to scroll as you wanted:

1. Make screenshot in current state
2. Scroll page by js to Up position
3. Make screenshot again in Up state
4. Diff two screenshots

If you want to now is element visible on page (in browser after some scroll) you can:

1. Get element position on page (in pxls): x, y, height_x, weight_y
2. Get page screenshot
3. Get element screenshot
4. Cut page screenshot to rectangle image (by element coordinates, step1)
5. Diff element screenshot and rectangle image

In both ways steps 1-3 is simple selenium web-driver actions(I can illustrated on java only). For diff images recommend to use imageMagic

Answer (score 0):

Use the `Displayed` property

```
element.Displayed;
```

Will return `true` or `false`.

Comment: No, after click on button, page scroll to some header on the page. element.Displayed returns true before the action and after. I wanna know that scroll was be